# Mapping widget for Qt

Tags: qt, dictionary, widget

I need a Qt widget that will allow me to display a map.

It needs to be able to:

- Run without a network connection to a map or tile server.  A simple bitmap would be fine.
- Place widgets, lines and graphics on the map, given latitude and longitude.
- Calculate distances between points.
- Compile on Linux and Windows.

What would you suggest?

Thanks,
sqqqrly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a looking at [Marble](http://api.kde.org/4.x-api/kdeedu-apidocs/marble/html/index.html).

It's included with KDE-edu, but if I recall correctly, the Marble library does *not* have any dependencies beyond just Qt, it's also under the LGPL, and it's cross-platform. You should be able to place widgets and various other things on the surface.

Comment: I have been looking at marble.  It looks perfect.  I do not see how to use map data that is local to the app.   It seems to be geared to openmap, google maps, etc.

OpenMapControl seems to be the same way. This does say it can use persistent tiles, but how does one make that data set? 

I sent emails to the developers for both tools.  

I see it is possible to create a tile server, but I'd rather not. I only need a small bitmap and I have a database that is serving up, via CORBA, all the rest of my configuration data for many apps. This is a small part of a large distributed system.
Thanks!

Comment: Marble has different flavors, one of which is QT only, another is a kpart, so that works.

Answer (score 2):

[Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org) is the leader of the pack.

Comment: This tool is GPL'd and I do not think it supports Qt.

Comment: Quoting http://qgis.org/en/about-qgis.html for you, then: "The name Quantum GIS really has no siginificance, other than it starts with a Q and QGIS uses the excellent Qt Toolkit from trolltech.com." :o

Answer (score 1):

There is a map editor written for OpenStreetMap, which uses Qt.
http://www.merkaartor.org/

For map rendering they uses Webkit, I guess, but not really sure. Try to contact the author or read the source.

Answer (score 0):

Hi every one [QMapControl](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qmapcontrol/) and [ArcGIS](https://developers.arcgis.com/qt/) could be a good try.